# Modem identified as Wifi

Tags: usb-modem, router

I have a ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM modem . When I connect it to the machine, it gets identified correctly in `lsusb` as `MF79 (19d2:1405)`.

The problem is that in `ifconfig` it shows it's IP as `192.168.0.[some_number]`, which, as I get it, specifies that I am connected to some wireless local network which provides me internet. Because of that I cannot see information using Modem Manager. The command `sudo mmcli -L` shows that there is no modem connected.

The modem is working in WiFi router mode, so other devices can also connect to it. Is it possible to change it somehow, so it would behave like a default modem instead of a router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer from another forum, if anyone interesed here is reply

> MF79 (19d2:1405) is not a dialup modem, it is a direct ethernet adapter ie a modern Mobile Broadband device for higher speed than a dialup modem can offer.
>
> Ethernet does not have a management protocol so ModemManager can't do
>   anything with the device, everything is handled by NetworkManager.
>
> You will not be able to get a public ip address with a device like
>   this that has a wifi access point built in, the device has to do NAT
>   and hence the address you get on the usb ethernet connection is a
>   private ip from the device LAN where wifi also resides. @LOM